# highlight specific gene name in pheatmap

Tags: r, pheatmap

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to highlight some gene names(row names) in the heatmap package? I want to highlight the row names "I", "H", and "G" in a different color(red color) keep the rest as it is.
Here is my code

```
set.seed(22)
li.A <- matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 10)
rownames(li.A) <- LETTERS[1:10]
colnames(li.A) <- paste0("S_", ncol = 1:5)
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(li.A)
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This page has the answer
https://github.com/raivokolde/pheatmap/issues/48
Best,
Amare